# Getting an Object[] Information to ArrayList and present it on List View Layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm starting on android dev and I'm trying to make an object array appear at a list view. I've searched some information and all of them used a single array to present information into a certain textfield.

What I've found:

```
String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
    "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
    "Linux", "OS/2" };

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.LAYOUT, R.id.txtFIELD, values);
```

This code works fine, but my layout has 3 Strings in each object on the array. So what should I do to show three different object's information into its respective txt fields at an Layout?

More details:

```
//The Object
public class MessageItem {
    String temp;
    String time;
    String date;
}
```

---

```
//The fields of the XML layout of the intended ListView disposition
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/temp"
></TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
></TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
></TextView>
```

---

```
//Am I on the right track doing this?

ArrayAdapter<MessageItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MessageItem>(this,R.layout.XMLlayou);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write your own adapter class, and in its `getView` method, set text for all textview in a row.

**Example:**

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    @Override

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row.xml, null);

            holder.txtViewTemp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.temp);
            holder.txtViewTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            holder.txtViewDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        //here myObj will be your array of objects from which you would retrieve data based on position.
        holder.txtViewTemp.setText(myObj[position].getTemp());
        holder.txtViewTime.setText(myObj[position].getTime());
        holder.txtViewDate.setText(myObj[position].getDate());
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Then use this adapter instead of ListView default adapter.

Refer this: [ListView with Two TextViews and ImageView](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-listview-3-custom-listview/)

Which will help you understand more about it.

Hope it helps.